sizeof() operator in c++ displaying different results in case of arrays
Why is the result of the two array sizes are different?
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void fun(int a[]){
    cout <<sizeof(a)/sizeof(int)<<" ";
    cout<<endl;
    
}

int main() {
    int a[5]={1,2,3,4,5};
    cout <<sizeof(a)/sizeof(int)<<" ";
    cout<<endl;
    fun(a);
    return 0;
}

Output:
5  2
Why is the output not as follows?
5  5

a in fun is not an array, it's a pointer and you are seeing the size of the pointer

This question is similar to: Passing Arrays to Function in C++. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

In C++ you can instead use std::size(a) that will either give the correct result or fail to compile.

It's "array decay to pointer" - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1461449/1607937

In modern C++ take a look on std::size std::ssize std::span std::array.

void fun(int a[]){ whover taught you this hasn't caught up with C++ since 1998. From that moment we have std::vector, std::array.  And both of them have a .size() method. Side note, stop using using namespace std; too

If you use a C++ style array (std::array) instead of a C style array, this problem should go away.
